# Include .js file in another javascript file in alfresco

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I'm working with alfresco and was wondering how to include a js file in another file. How do I deal with dependency when I want to use a library?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/API-JS-Scripts.html, or something more precise ?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I am looking for!! I search a lot but never found that page, thanks a lot :D

Comment: You guys should move this to an answer and accept it as a correct one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Lista suggested, I created an answer :

I think this is what you need (from [Alfresco documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/API-JS-Scripts.html)) :

> **Importing scripts**
>
> This feature allows you to build libraries of scripts for use by other
>   scripts at runtime. The syntax to import the scripts is specific to
>   Alfresco and is not a feature of standard JavaScript. For example, the
>    syntax, as supported by most web browsers, is not
>   part of standard ECMA JavaScript and will not work in Alfresco.
>
> The syntax to import other scripts is very strict and you must follow
>   it exactly; otherwise, the import may fail. Import directives must be
>   the first lines in the JavaScript file. This means that no code or
>   comments are allowed above those lines, and the usual JavaScript code
>   and comments appear after the import lines. Only the following syntax
>   variants are supported:
>
> - Import a script from the repository using a name-based path:
>
>   ```
>   <import resource="/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Scripts/library.js">
>   ```
> - Import a script from the repository using a NodeRef reference:
>
>   ```
>   <import resource="workspace://SpacesStore/6f73de1b-d3b4-11db-80cb-112e6c2ea048">
>   ```
> - Import a script from a Java classpath location:
>
>   ```
>   <import resource="classpath:alfresco/extension/myutils.js">
>   ```